# WPF Viewbox and WebBrowser controls

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Does someone know why WPF `Viewbox` control doesn't scale WPF `WebBrowser` control?

Is it possible to do at all?

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication12.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="Yellow">
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
<WebBrowser VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Source="http://stackoverflow.com"></WebBrowser>
</Viewbox>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it inherits from : `System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost` (that hosts a Win32 window)

It is not a pure WPF object.

Then effect, scaling, etc, can't apply on it.

WPF 4.5 Developer Preview supported scaling, rotation, skewing of HwndHost controls but they seem to have removed this feature in the final release.

Comment: @Peretz That is exactly what I mean.

Comment: So what alternatives would you recommend? Altering the html programmatically to appear at different sizes? Converting the HTML to XAML?